# Using higher order components with Redux containers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

First, some context.

I'm using Redux to manage authentication state of my app and have `Auth` as a Redux container (or smart component).

I've created a wrapper (a higher-order component) that takes `Auth` and returns it:

```
export default function AuthWrapper(WrappedComponent) {
  class Auth extends Component {
  ... <Auth stuff here> ...
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Auth);
}
```

It seems to me that in order to use the wrapper, I just need to invoke it with a component I want to have behind my auth. For example, let's say I'm authenticating a component called `UserPage` with the wrapper, à la:

`const AuthenticatedUserPage = AuthWappper(UserPage)`

However, when I use the wrapper like this, React isn't happy with me. I get the following error:

```
Warning: AuthenticatedApp(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

My best guess is that it doesn't like the `connect`-ified component that Redux will create when I return it from `AuthWrapper`... which leads me to my question:

Does React support higher-order components when those components create Redux containers? And if so, why would React be throwing this error?

Comment: also important: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307736/redux-higher-order-components-same-as-container-components?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my two cents. I think the error is occurring elsewhere.

According to this simplified version of the `connect` function in react-redux, the connect function is simply returning another react component. So in your case, **you're returning a component, wrapped inside another component**, which is still valid. **A container is basically a component.**

Read https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1d19088790e70ac32ea636c025ba424e for a better understanding of the connect function.

I also tried the following in my own application and it worked.

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
//Do some other imports and stuff
function wrapper(Layout) {
  return connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Layout);
}
export default wrapper()
```

Like the error states, you might just simply be returning an invalid component somewhere in your app. Your app might be throwing the error because you're not wrapping a return call in parentheses on your render method.